How to: Make animated "chain lightning" effect in Flutter Flame between two game components?
How to: Make animated "chain lightning" effect in Flutter Flame between two game components?
So as I see this problem:

How to connect 2 moving game components with a simple line (that updates it's position each frame). This one I think is duable by drawing line on canvas.
How to apply to this line some "chain lightning" (or any other) sprite effect? (So draw some repeatable sprite between two components)

Or what is best practice to do such kind of things in Flutter Flame / other game engines?


Create a LineComponent that you pass in the two game components to and then override render and draw a line between component1.position and component2.position.

It depends a bit what the effect should look like, you could either make it with the ParticleSystemComponent or many components with the MoveToEffect.


